# Using a div as a filler

Tags: css, html

I appreciate this maybe a simple question but I cannot find the answer.

I have a div. Inside that div I have 3 columns (made up of divs).

The 1st div has some text in it and the 3rd div had some text in it as well.  I want the middle div to take up all the remaining space.

I have played around with absolute,fixed and relative positions.

This is what I mean:

```
<div id="divheader">
    <div style="float: left; width: 85px;">Caption to the left</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">this div has no caption but I want it to take up the remaining space</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 185px;">caption to the right</div>
</div>
<div id="divpage">
    stuff
</div>
<div id="divfooter">
    footer stuff
```

Comment: Do you want the middle div to have any formatting or is it purely to make the last div go right?

Comment: thanks for taking an interest. I would like the last div to go right.  But bear in mind this is my header and that I will be having a div page and div footer (I will amend question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could float the last div right and not worry about having a div in the middle if you are not using it for any purpose.

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 85px;">Caption to the left</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 185px;">caption to the right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This suited my immediate needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `table-cell` display for this exact purpose.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divided">
    <div style="width: 85px;">Caption to the left</div>
    <div>this div has no caption but I want it to take up the remaining space</div>
    <div style="width: 185px;">caption to the right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.divided {
   display: table;
}
.divided > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/M743D/1/)

- [Browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell): Works great with modern browsers.

Comment: +1 : for the solution :) I supposed to do the same :)

Comment: hi, thanks for this. Very informative. I prefer the answer from @fraggy but I will probably use this elsewhere where I would want the middle diff to have some content/formatting. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the display table (the advantage of doing it this way is that it will also keep all three columns the same height):

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%">
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 85px;">Caption to the left</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;">this div has no caption but I want it to take up the remaining space</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width: 185px;">caption to the right</div>
</div><br />
```

Or if you want it to be more compatible with older browsers then you can use padding and negative margins:

```
<div style="padding:0 185px 0 85px">
    <div style="float: left; width: 85px; margin-left:-85px;">Caption to the left</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">this div has no caption but I want it to take up the remaining space</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 185px; margin-right:-185px;">caption to the right</div>
</div>
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCt8Z/1/)

Comment: hi, thanks for this. Very informative. I prefer the answer from @fraggy but I will probably use this elsewhere where I would want the middle diff to have some content/formatting. +1